# SELECT TOP is slow, regardless of ORDER BY

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql, sql-execution-plan, query-hints

I have a fairly complex query in SQL Server running against a view, in the form:

```
SELECT *
   FROM myview, foo, bar 
   WHERE shared=1 AND [joins and other stuff]
   ORDER BY sortcode;
```

The query plan as shown above shows a `Sort` operation just before the final `SELECT`, which is what I would expect. There are only 35 matching records, and the query takes well under 2 seconds.

But if I add `TOP 30`, the query takes almost 3 minutes! Using `SET ROWCOUNT` is just as slow.

Looking at the query plan, it now appears to sort all 2+ million records in `myview` *before* the joins and filters.

*This "sorting" is shown on the query plan as an Index Scan on the `sortcode` index, a Clustered Index Seek on the main table, and a Nested Loop between them, all before the joins and filters.*

**How can I force SQL Server to `SORT` *just before* `TOP`, like it does when `TOP` isn't specified?**

I don't think the construction of `myview` is the issue, but just in case, it is something like this:

```
CREATE VIEW myview AS
   SELECT columns..., sortcode, 0 as shared FROM mytable
   UNION ALL
   SELECT columns..., sortcode, 1 as shared FROM [anotherdb].dbo.mytable
```

The local `mytable` has a few thousand records, and `mytable` in the other database in the same MSSQL instance has a few million records. Both tables **do have indexes** on their respective `sortcode` column.

Comment: So, the `WHERE shared=1` in your query actually cancels the first part of the `UNION` view?

Comment: @ypercube, yes, in the case of this particular query.

Comment: It wouldn't hurt if you posted the whole `[joins and other stuff]` part of the query. Perhaps some other index missing is what causes the optimizer to take the slow path.

Answer (score 12):

And so starts the unfortunate game of "trying to outsmart the optimizer (because it doesn't always know best)".

You can try putting the filtering portions into a subquery or CTE:

```
SELECT TOP 30 *
FROM
   (SELECT *
   FROM myview, foo, bar 
   WHERE shared=1 AND [joins and other stuff]) t
ORDER BY sortcode;
```

Which may be enough to force it to filter first (but the optimizer gets "smarter" with each release, and can sometimes see through such shenanigans). Or you might have to go as far as putting this code into a [UDF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186755.aspx). If you write the UDF as a multistatement table-valued function, with the filtering inside, and then query that UDF with your `TOP x`/`ORDER BY`, you've pretty well forced the querying order (because SQL Server is currently unable to optimize around multistatement UDFs).

---

Of course, thinking about it, introducing the UDF is just a way of hiding what we're really doing - create a temp table, use one query to populate it (based on WHERE filters), then another query to find the `TOP x` from the temp table.

Comment: Tip: Do include the `ORDER BY` otherwise this trick won't work!